# Why does current increase in step-down transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

I'm trying to make sense of transformers.

$\varepsilon_{p} = $ emf in primary coil, $\varepsilon_{s} = $ induced emf in secondary coil, $N_{p} = $ number of turns in primary coil, $N_{s} = $ number of turns in secondary coil, $\frac{d \phi}{d t} = $ change of magnetic flux.

The first thing that confuses me is derivation. My textbook states the induced emf in the secondary coil is equal to:
$$\varepsilon_{s} = N_{s} \frac{d \phi}{d t}$$
Additionally, it says that the magnetic flux through the secondary coil should be equal to the flux through the primary coil. It does seem sensible to me, given that the energy loss is assumed to be negligible. However, my problems begin when it states that the emf in the primary coil is also equal to:
$$\varepsilon_{p} = N_{p} \frac{d \phi}{d t}$$
Doesn't this formula only apply to the induced emf? And it should hold for emf created otherwise. Or am I missing something?

My second problem is that the conclusion that we arrive at my this logic chain:
$$\frac{\varepsilon_{p}}{\varepsilon_{s}} = \frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}$$
, energy is conserved, so $P_{p}=P_{s}$. Hence:
$$\varepsilon_{p} I_{p} = \varepsilon_{s} I_{s}$$
$$\frac{I_{s}}{I_{p}} = \frac{\varepsilon_{p}}{\varepsilon_{s}} = \frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}$$
It follows from it that if emf in the secondary coil is higher, then the current in the secondary coil is smaller. The way I see it, the only way it's possible is if resistance in the secondary coil is higher. So I did the following analysis:
$$P_{p}=P_{s}$$
$$I_{p}^2 R_{p} = I_{s}^2 R_{s}$$
$$\frac{R_{p}}{R_{s}} = \frac{I_{s}^2}{I_{p}^2} = \frac{N_{p}^2}{N_{s}^2}$$
So it follows that the resistance is proportional to the square of the number of turns, which doesn't make sense to me as the number of turns increases the length of the coil linearly and not quadratically. Could someone explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to model transformers than that- as follows.

Think of a step down transformer as if it were a *gear box* with a certain *gear ratio*. The analogous variables are voltage for torque and current for RPM.  Then, a step-down gearbox takes high RPM (current) and low torque (voltage) and produces low RPM (current) and high torque (voltage), and vice versa.

In this sense, the gear ratio of the gearbox is analogous to the *turns ratio* of the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct: this is what we call impedance seen from the primary when the secondary is loaded. It is the interpretation that is incorrect.

Remember that you are using the perfect transformer model for which the winding resistances are neglected. Therefore, we cannot involve the resistances of the windings. Here, it is a phenomenon of induction: when the secondary is connected to a load, current flows in the secondary and the magnetic flux sent by the secondary to the primary is modified. The counter electromotive force at the primary is changed and, for the same voltage at the primary, the current absorbed by the primary adapts. This is the origin of the impedance seen from the primary. For example, if you reduce the resistance connected to the secondary, the current drawn by the primary will increase accordingly: the impedance seen from the primary will also decrease.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does current increase in step-down transformer?

Ideally power in equals power out so VI in equals VI out.
For example if volts in is halfed current out is doubled.